# How to create a redshift table from existing cluster using typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-redshift, cluster-computing, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I have a ec2 instance from which I'm trying to connect to redshift cluster. With the below code I'm able to create a new redshift cluster but I am looking for examples as to how I can connect to an existing redshift cluster.

```
const cluster = new Cluster(this, YYYY, {
      clusterName: 'XXXXXX',
      clusterType: ClusterType.SINGLE_NODE,
      defaultDatabaseName: databaseName,
      masterUser: {
        masterUsername: 'admin_user',
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Amazon Redshift by using a JDBC connection ([drivers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/jdbc20-download-driver.html)), or anything that would connect to a PostgreSQL database.

Alternatively, you can [Use the Amazon Redshift Data API - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html), which accesses the database via an AWS API call.